# view can not identify variable from controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

everyone! I got a problem in rails.
I have some code like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def index
@users = User.all
end
```

---

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
      <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><%=stt%></td>
                <td> <%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
                <td><%=user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name%></td>
                <td><%=user.phone%></td>
          <td><%=user.email%></td>
            </tr>
      </tbody>
```

---

It's okay in local, but when I deploy it on host, there is an error:

```
Started GET "/users" for 180.93.29.249 at 2016-06-20 06:34:34 +0000
App 7027 stdout: Processing by UsersController#index as HTML
App 7027 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[36mUser Load (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", 1]]
App 7027 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[35mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
App 7027 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[36mCACHE (0.0ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", 1]]
App 7027 stdout:   ^[[1m^[[35mUser Load (0.5ms)^[[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
App 7027 stdout:   Rendered users/index.html.erb within layouts/application (80.6ms)
App 7027 stdout: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 241ms (ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
App 7027 stdout:
App 7027 stdout: ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):
App 7027 stdout:     31:                        <tr>
App 7027 stdout:     32:                                <td><%=stt%></td>
App 7027 stdout:     33:                                <td> <%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
App 7027 stdout:     34:                                <td><%=user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name%></td>
App 7027 stdout:     35:                                <td><%=user.phone%></td>
App 7027 stdout:     36:               <td><%=user.email%></td>
App 7027 stdout:     37:               <%stt+=1%>
App 7027 stdout:   app/views/users/index.html.erb:34:in `block in _app_views_users_index_html_erb___2721014350791878178_25989480'
App 7027 stdout:   app/views/users/index.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_users_index_html_erb___2721014350791878178_25989480'
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite following as:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%=stt%></td>
            <td> <%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
            <td><%= "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}" %></td>
            <td><%= user.phone %></td>
      <td><%=user.email%></td>
        </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: I don't think that's the point. because it's ok when i use '+' method for string. but the view can not identify the @users from controller

Comment: That reason you got a problem. Because in special case, `user.first_name` or `user.last_name` can return `nil`. And `nil` + `string' will throw an error as you saw on your console.

If you use "#{} #{}" as i wrote, it will return nil, it don't throw error